# how to select front camera from device in Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, android-camera

Well, i'm fairly new to unity and a real noob in what's about textures, but i managed to use a device's camera (using the code at the end of this post)

The problem is that I'd like to use the front camera when using smartphone devices.
Is there a noob way to do it?

Thanks for your attention, time and help <3

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CameraScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    static WebCamTexture backCam;

    void Start()
    {
        if (backCam == null)
            backCam = new WebCamTexture();

        GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = backCam;

        this.GetComponent<RawImage>().material = this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().material;

        if (!backCam.isPlaying)
            backCam.Play();

    } 
}
```

Comment: please use the correct tags ... [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long deprecated by now ... your code is clearly `c#`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you use the front facing camera in Unity:

```
public class CameraScript : MonoBehaviour
{    
    WebCamTexture = null;

    void Start()
    {
       WebCamDevice[] devices = WebCamTexture.devices;

       foreach (var device in devices) {
         if (device.isFrontFacing) {
           webCamTexture = new WebCamTexture(device.name);
         }
       }
 
       if (webCamTexture == null) {
         webCamTexture = new WebCamTexture();
       }
    }
}
```

If no front facing camera is available then `WebCamDevice` defaults to an empty constructor `WebCamTexture` in the example I have provided.

It's good to refer to the Unity Documentation, although it's not always the best documentation out there.

Here is the [WebCamTexture](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WebCamTexture.html) documentation.

Here is the [WebCamDevice](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WebCamDevice.html) documentation.

The [Unity forums](https://forum.unity.com/) also contain a wealth of information and, depending on the problem, the Unity Engine Developers will sometimes answer questions.

Comment: Woah!!!! that worked perfectly... I've been the last days without understanding much.
And you answer and also give me some usefull documentation and tips... THANKS!!!!!